# wordpress apply_filter values are not coming inline

Tags: wordpress

I am using follwing code in my wordpress custom theme template

```
<p id="news"> <?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$myNews)?></p>;
```

And the desired output should be like this

```
<p id="news"> Herer goes my news content from $myNewsvariable </p>
```

But i am getting output like this

```
<p id="news"></p>Here goes my news content from $myNewsvariable
```

Please tell me how i can fix this

Comment: and where is the code?

Comment: i edited it .. plz check

Answer (score 1):

`the_content` function prints out content by default. So there is no need to do a duplicate `echo` before `apply_filters`.

Also you can apply your filter to `get_the_content`:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('get_the_content', $myNews); ?>
```

Comment: i am using the [latex] in filter , after removing echo its not displaying the output